# how to 'encode' the body in an HTTP body?

Tags: api, httprequest, http, character-encoding, encodingutil

i am trying to send this body exactly as it looks

```
{
    "table":"inquiries",
    "response_type":"json",
    "query_array":"{\"fname\":\"Test\"}"
}
```

this body works and returns a successful response in postman
so in my apex class I have it as

```
String body = '{"table":"inquiries",' +
              ' "response_type":"json", ' +
              ' "query_array":"{\"fname\":\"Test\"}" }';
```

however this returns a 404, and when i look at the debug the body is being sent as :

```
{
  "table":"inquiries", 
  "response_type":"json",  
  "query_array":"{"fname":"Test"}" 
}
```

how can I make the body look like the first??

Answer (score 1):

In Apex Code, `\` is a source code escape character. That means to get a literal `\`, you need to type `\\` instead. For this reason, among others, I always prefer to use `JSON.serialize`; it takes more code, but is easier to maintain. Here's how I would write this:

```
String jsonOutput = JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> {
        'table' => 'inquiries',
        'response_type' => 'json',
        'query_array' => JSON.serialize(
            new Map<String, Object> {
                'fname' => 'Test'
            }
        )
    }
);
```

Note that the parameters may not appear in the same order, but any sane JSON parser will be able to read this exactly as needed.

Comment: thanks! that worked.